# HTTP_RECEIVE_REQUEST_FLAG_FLUSH_BODY doesn't copy http body

Tags: c++, windows, http, httpserver, simplehttpserver

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `HTTP_RECEIVE_REQUEST_FLAG_FLUSH_BODY` flag passed into the `HttpReceiveHttpRequest` function causes the entity bodies to be copied into the `HTTP_REQUEST` structure that is passed in.

I wrote a simple http server (see below) that invokes this function with this flag set. I then sent a 4MB `POST` request from a test client and attached a debugger to the http server to see how many bytes were copied into the `HTTP_REQUEST` structure after the function returned; I observed this didn't copy the http body, only the header was copied.

Is there a way of making `HttpReceiveHttpRequest` copy the entire 4MB body into the `pEntityChunks` portion of the HTTP request?

Note: I verified `HttpReceiveRequestEntityBody` function does copy the whole body when the `HTTP_RECEIVE_REQUEST_ENTITY_BODY_FLAG_FILL_BUFFER` flag is set.

**HTTP Server**

```
// HttpServer.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#endif

#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <http.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

#pragma comment(lib, "httpapi.lib")

int RequestBufferLength = 4194304 + 4096;
int ResponseBufferLength = 4194304;
int SmallBufferLength = 100;

std::unique_ptr<char[]> ResponseBuffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(ResponseBufferLength);
std::unique_ptr<char[]> SmallBuffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(SmallBufferLength);
std::unique_ptr<char[]> RequestBuffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(RequestBufferLength);

DWORD SendHttpResponse(HANDLE hReqQueue, PHTTP_REQUEST pRequest)
{
    HTTP_RESPONSE response;
    HTTP_DATA_CHUNK dataChunk;
    DWORD result;
    DWORD bytesSent;

    // Initialize the HTTP response structure.
    RtlZeroMemory(&response, sizeof(response));
    response.StatusCode = 200;                      
    response.pReason = "OK";                         
    response.ReasonLength = 2;

    // Add known headers.
    std::string contentType = "text/html";
    response.Headers.KnownHeaders[HttpHeaderContentType].pRawValue = contentType.c_str();
    response.Headers.KnownHeaders[HttpHeaderContentType].RawValueLength = (USHORT)contentType.length();

    // Add the body
    if (pRequest->Verb == HttpVerbGET)
    {
        // Send big response
        dataChunk.DataChunkType = HttpDataChunkFromMemory;
        dataChunk.FromMemory.pBuffer = ResponseBuffer.get();
        dataChunk.FromMemory.BufferLength = ResponseBufferLength;
    }
    else
    {
        // Send small response
        dataChunk.DataChunkType = HttpDataChunkFromMemory;
        dataChunk.FromMemory.pBuffer = SmallBuffer.get();
        dataChunk.FromMemory.BufferLength = SmallBufferLength;
    }

    response.EntityChunkCount = 1;
    response.pEntityChunks = &dataChunk;

    // Because the entity body is sent in one call, it is not
    // required to specify the Content-Length.
    result = HttpSendHttpResponse(
        hReqQueue,           // ReqQueueHandle
        pRequest->RequestId, // Request ID
        0,                   // Flags
        &response,           // HTTP response
        NULL,                // HTTP Cache Policy
        &bytesSent,          // bytes sent  (OPTIONAL)
        NULL,                // pReserved2  (must be NULL)
        0,                   // Reserved3   (must be 0)
        NULL,                // LPOVERLAPPED(OPTIONAL)
        NULL                 // pReserved4  (must be NULL)
        );

    if (result != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpSendHttpResponse failed with %lu \n", result);
    }

    return result;
}

DWORD ReceiveRequests(HANDLE hReqQueue)
{
    ULONG result;
    HTTP_REQUEST_ID requestId;
    DWORD bytesRead;
    PHTTP_REQUEST pRequest;

    pRequest = (PHTTP_REQUEST)RequestBuffer.get();

    // Wait for a new request. This is indicated by a NULL 
    // request ID.
    HTTP_SET_NULL_ID(&requestId);

    for (;;)
    {
        result = HttpReceiveHttpRequest(
            hReqQueue,
            requestId,
            HTTP_RECEIVE_REQUEST_FLAG_FLUSH_BODY,
            pRequest,
            RequestBufferLength,
            &bytesRead,
            NULL);

        if (NO_ERROR == result)
        {
            switch (pRequest->Verb)
            {
            case HttpVerbGET:
                result = SendHttpResponse(hReqQueue, pRequest);
                break;
            case HttpVerbPUT:
            case HttpVerbPOST:
                result = HttpReceiveRequestEntityBody(
                    hReqQueue,
                    pRequest->RequestId,
                    HTTP_RECEIVE_REQUEST_ENTITY_BODY_FLAG_FILL_BUFFER,
                    RequestBuffer.get() + bytesRead,
                    RequestBufferLength - bytesRead,
                    &bytesRead,
                    NULL);

                if (NO_ERROR == result)
                {
                    result = SendHttpResponse(hReqQueue, pRequest);
                }
                break;
            default:
                wprintf(L"Got a unknown request for %ws \n", pRequest->CookedUrl.pFullUrl);
                result = E_FAIL;
                break;
            }

            if (result != NO_ERROR)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Reset the Request ID to handle the next request.
            HTTP_SET_NULL_ID(&requestId);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::wstring url;
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        url = L"http://127.0.0.1:80/NativeBigDataTest";
    }
    else
    {
        std::string serverIp(argv[1]);
        url = L"http://" + std::wstring(serverIp.begin(), serverIp.end()) + L":80/NativeBigDataTest";
    }    

    HTTP_SERVER_SESSION_ID session;
    HTTP_URL_GROUP_ID urlGroup;
    HANDLE hReqQueue = NULL;
    HTTP_BINDING_INFO bindingInfo;
    ULONG retCode;

    // Initialize HTTP Server APIs
    retCode = HttpInitialize(
                    HTTPAPI_VERSION_2,
                    HTTP_INITIALIZE_SERVER,    // Flags
                    NULL                       // Reserved
                    );
    if (retCode != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpInitialize failed with %lu \n", retCode);
        return retCode;
    }

    // Create server session    
    retCode = HttpCreateServerSession(HTTPAPI_VERSION_2, &session, 0);
    if (retCode != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpCreateServerSession failed with %lu \n", retCode);
        goto CleanUp5;
    }

    // Create Url Group    
    retCode = HttpCreateUrlGroup(session, &urlGroup, 0);
    if (retCode != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpCreateUrlGroup failed with %lu \n", retCode);
        goto CleanUp4;
    }

    // Add url to group
    retCode = HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup(urlGroup, url.c_str(), HTTP_URL_CONTEXT{}, 0);
    if (retCode != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup failed with %lu \n", retCode);
        goto CleanUp3;
    }

    // Create a Request Queue Handle    
    retCode = HttpCreateRequestQueue(HTTPAPI_VERSION_2, NULL, NULL, 0, &hReqQueue);
    if (retCode != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpCreateHttpHandle failed with %lu \n", retCode);
        goto CleanUp2;
    }

    // Bind request queue to url group    
    bindingInfo.RequestQueueHandle = hReqQueue;
    bindingInfo.Flags.Present = 1;
    retCode = HttpSetUrlGroupProperty(urlGroup, HttpServerBindingProperty, &bindingInfo, sizeof(bindingInfo));
    if (retCode != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpSetUrlGroupProperty failed with %lu \n", retCode);
        goto CleanUp1;
    }

    wprintf(L"Listening on url %s\n", url.c_str());

    // Receive requests
    ReceiveRequests(hReqQueue);

CleanUp1:
    // Close the Request Queue handle.
    retCode = HttpCloseRequestQueue(hReqQueue);
    if (retCode != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpCloseRequestQueue failed with %lu \n", retCode);
    }

CleanUp2:
    // Call HttpRemoveUrlFromUrlGroup for all added URLs.
    retCode = HttpRemoveUrlFromUrlGroup(
        urlGroup,
        url.c_str(),
        0);
    if (retCode != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpRemoveUrlFromUrlGroup failed with %lu \n", retCode);
    }

CleanUp3:
    // Close Url group
    retCode = HttpCloseUrlGroup(urlGroup);
    if (retCode != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpCloseUrlGroup failed with %lu \n", retCode);
    }

CleanUp4:
    // Close Session
    retCode = HttpCloseServerSession(session);
    if (retCode != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpCloseServerSession failed with %lu \n", retCode);
    }

CleanUp5:
    // Call HttpTerminate.
    retCode = HttpTerminate(HTTP_INITIALIZE_SERVER, NULL);
    if (retCode != NO_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"HttpTerminate failed with %lu \n", retCode);
    }

    return retCode;
}
```

Comment: Have you come to any conclusions about this? I see the same behaviour using the HTTP_RECEIVE_REQUEST_FLAG_COPY_BODY flag as well. Currently, I call HttpReceiveRequestEntityBody but it would be nice to have everything done in one call.

Comment: No, I too just used HttpReceiveRequestEntityBody to retrieve the entire body. HttpReceiveHttpRequest only copies what is available with the header and doesn't block till the full body is received.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing a lot of logging in my own HTTPServer that's using the HttpReceiveHttpRequest function, I found out that if I was NOT using the HTTP_RECEIVE_REQUEST_ENTITY_BODY_FLAG_FILL_BUFFER flag, It would Always receive a package of 1 byte first, and after that receive a full buffer. (behold: I found this behaviour on MS-Windows 8). If I did use the forementioned flag, it would receive a buffer right away in one go, even the very first time.

I do not know wheter this would mean more or less roundtrips, but on larger files the throughput measured in milliseconds was almost down to the 50% after using this flag.

Please test on other versions of MS-Windows as well!